# Difficulty in sending message containing user's longitude and latitude from user to a friend(message always show 0.0 0.0 as lon n lat)

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget, android-manifest

I have written a code for sending sms to the friend but now I want to send longitude and latitude to friend.I modified my code but it is always sending " 0.0 0.0 " as longitude and latitude to friend.What is going wrong with the code.Can anyone help me with this?

Here is my manifest file :

http://pastebin.com/wLiHDs3A

Here is my .java file :
http://pastebin.com/nCmpneB8

Here is my main.xml file :

http://pastebin.com/m52f31eT

Comment: @Randy : variables which will hold the longitude and latitude are double and I have declared them just after starting of class.Take a look at my code.And please let me know where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you testing this out on the emlator? If so, then the GPS coordinates probably aren't set and therefore it has nothing valid to transmit. To set the gps coordinates on your emulator do:

```
telnet localhost 5554 geo fix <longitude value> <latitude value>
```

This will set the latitude and longitude on the emulator. Then try running your app.

Comment: Well I have tried sending longitude and latitude values using both telnet and DDMS but it is sending only " 0.0 0.0 " I don't know what's going wrong.